# XAMPP control panel not updating but MySQL is already running

Tags: mysql, xampp

[image: The control panel not working]

I have an issue. MySQL server is already running while the XAMPP control panel is not updating accordingly. May I ask how to have the control panel showing the port is running instead of stucking?

Comment: *"MySQL server is already running"* - which mysql? did you have mysql installed separately?

Comment: How to figure out where is the problem? As I could access the phpmyadmin database but the panel still could not be updated